# ReSharper 5 Search with Pattern

Tags: regex, search, resharper, resharper-5.0

I just recently ran into the "Search with Pattern" tool in the new ReSharper.

I tried to search for

```
private $Type$ $Var$ = new $Type$($TypeArgs$);
```

but when I search it just says "Cannot parse pattern"

when I take way the private access modifier it works. But I am trying to explicitly search for it with the access modifier.

I have also tried

```
$Modifier$ $Type$ $Var$ = new $Type$($TypeArgs$);
```

and that also returns "Cannot parse pattern"

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently Search with Pattern can only search inside method body, not for a class member.

Comment: Has this been written up in YouTrack yet, so we can vote for it?

Comment: Has this been fixed yet?  I've just spent the last half hour trying to do this (unsuccessfully).  It sure SEEMS like it should be able to since I get other resharper hints for class members.